# Conditional Allocation of Variable SIzed Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I've been trying to do this ALL this weekend and this C++ language seems to be really useless under certain obvious situations.

I need to create 21 integer vectors conditionally, through an if or switch clause, that is (please note this is referencial code only):

```
vector<int> vec;
if (i=1)
    vec=<..some vector definition..>;
elseif (i=2)
    vec=<..other vector definition..>;
...
<some variable>=vec[<some proper index>];
```

21 vectors are most different in sizes,. Every declaration and or definition i made inside the if, or switch or any other clause get out of scope.

The ussual code (for the 21th vector):

```
static const int vec_aux21[] = {16,2,77,29};
vector<int> vec (vec_aux21, vec_aux21 + <vec_aux21_size> );
```

don't work, get out of scope when output the if or switch clause

Is there a SMART approach for this. What if they needed to be vectors of vectors of ints?

Comment: `std::vector<int> data[21]` with a proper initializer list. Either that or I really missed something in the admittedly convoluted description of this problem. What is stopping you from indexing into the array of vectors dependent on your switch conditions ?

Comment: As I understand, your problem is really in lack of understanding of OOPs concepts. You want to create a bunch of different objects driven by certain conditions? Creational design patterns such as builder pattern might come to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it this way, for example (this only considers 7 vectors of vectors of vectors of ints:

```
vector<vector< vector<int> > > movecube \
{{{1,0}},\
{{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{-1,-1}},\
{{2,1},{1,2},{-1,2},{-2,1},{-2,-1},{-1,-2},{1,-2},{2,-1}},\
{{1,1},{-1,1},{-1,-1},{1,-1}},\
{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0},{-1,-1},{0,-1},{1,-1}},\
{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0},{-1,-1},{0,-1},{1,-1}},\
{{0,0}}};
```

and then, inside every if or switch, place assignation to the herecalled movecube object. Thus the assignation will not fall out of scope, because you will be asigning an object already in general scope (not a particular scope of an if sentence clause...

This will require to activate -std=c++11 on your compiler.

Best wishes!

Hyp